# Do KMeans and creating a dendrogram produce the same labels?

Tags: python, label, k-means, dendrogram, unsupervised-learning

I am using some data to generate some labels so that I can sort my data to be used in a supervised learning environment. I have been generating a dendrogram to visualize how the data clusters but when I use KMeans to create the labels only a few of the labels show that they are in the shown cluster for the dendrogram.

code:

```
combined_array = pd.read_pickle('arrays.pickle')
model = KMeans(algorithm = 'auto', copy_x = True, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 300,
                n_clusters = 7, n_init = 10, n_jobs = 1, precompute_distances = 'auto',
                random_state = 1, tol = 0.0001, verbose = 0)
model.fit(combined_array)
labels = model.predict(combined_array)
pd.DataFrame(labels).to_csv("arrays_labels.csv")
mergings = linkage(combined_array, method = 'ward')
dendrogram(mergings, leaf_rotation = 0, leaf_font_size = 14, show_contracted = True)
```

[image]

The image above shows a section of what files should be in that cluster but when I use kmeans to generate labels only files `28, 33, 41, 45, 70` are included. So why aren't `13, 42, 67, 81` showing up in my labels? Do `KMeans` and `dendrogram` create different types of clustering?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really link your code to what you are asking, but yes! They're totally different!

Dendrogram is done by applying Hierarchical Clustering, very simple and DETERMINISTIC (you apply it 2 times? You'll get same result).
It works in this way:

```
1) Compute distance between points
2) Select the minimun distance
3) Aggregate the 2 points with minimum distance in a cluster 
4) Go to 1 until you get 1 cluster containing all elements
```

There are a lot of details omitted but this is the core. 
As you can see it's based on distance between points and does not tell you which cluster configuration is the best, there are techniques to select the number of clusters.

K-means needs to know previously the number of clusters you are looking for (see that you specify n_clusters in the code).

It works like this:

```
1) Randomly initialize n Centroids (center of mass of a cluster)
2) Assign each point to its closest centroid
3) Re-compute center of mass of the clusters created
4) Go to 2 until convergence
```

So - if I'm right - what you are trying to do is to generate labels from a clustering algorithm to then fit a supervised model.

So what you are looking for is simply **clustering model selection**.

To select the best number of clusters and the best algorithm there are a lot of techniques which highly depend on your problem and your data (have a deep look to [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) documentation before doing any kind of clustering)
If you want a general approach, try to look at [this](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_hdbscan.html) library which can select the best results among the ones you provide.

PS: An approach which can go well in general is [Silouhettes Analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html)